# I am unable to install and run app from Xcode on physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, fastlane, ios-provisioning

I have popup saying "Unable to install [App name]

```
Details

Unable to install "[App name]"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620395
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620395
Failure Reason: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124af06e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124af0de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124b3056a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010bfa1c12 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124b30301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001249c9a25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c0d2e7a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c0d4552 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67120583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6712150e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67126ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67127452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff67130a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6737b6fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6737a827 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

I have provisioning profiles managed by fastlane match and they are installed on my macOS keychain. Xcode project is set to use them in manual mode.

Tried cleaning DerivedData and MobileProvisioning profiles, removed and readded my developer account to Xcode. cleaned all certificates and provisioning profiles from developer portal and recreated them using `fastlane match`. No change ...

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and 11.4 beta (no change in behaviour between versions) on Catalina 10.15.3

Help really apreciated

Comment: Have you added the device? https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list

Comment: yes I have my device there

Answer (score 2):

After few hours yesterday and about 1h today I fixed this by setting different provisioning profiles for Debug and Release. I have no idea why both were set to Apple Distribution before. After this it worked.

[image: screenshot from Xcode]

Comment: I had that happening to me when I uploaded my app to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, If not using same team for all targets clean before and after switching to a build target and different team